# How to convert int32 unicode to string

Tags: go

I have a function that receives a list of hostnames , line by line, in an int32 slice format. This is the function:

```
func HandlePipeList(targetsList []int32) {
    //Print output item by item
    for i := 0; i < len(targetsList); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%c", targetsList[i])
    }
}
```

Since I'm converting it to `%c` with fmt, it works and prints the hostnames correctly.
My problem arises when I try to pass targetsList as a string to another function. How can I make the same convertion for targetsList so that the lines could be passed as string? (`strconv.Itoa` didn't work here).

Comment: Can you explain why you're using `%c` and not something else? What does each element in `targetList` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unicode code point in Go is a `rune`. Go type `rune` is an alias for Go type `int32`.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> ```
> int32   the set of all signed 32-bit integers
>
> rune    alias for int32
> ```
>
> [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions to and from a string type
>
> Converting a slice of runes to a string type yields a string that is
>   the concatenation of the individual rune values converted to strings.

---

Use a `string` type conversion. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    targetsList := []int32("Testing, testing, ...")

    str := string(targetsList)
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/d-s0uLFl9MG

Output:

```
Testing, testing, ...
```

---

Reference: [The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

Answer (score 0):

The [built-in rune type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) is just an alias for `int32`, so this is the same problem as converting a `[]rune` to `string`.  You might use something like `strings.Builder`(https://godoc.org/strings#Builder) to assemble the string:

```
func runesToString(l []int32) (string, error) {
    b := strings.Builder{}
    for _, n := range l {
        _, err := b.WriteRune(n)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
    }
    return b.String(), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MEXzsamubp6 has a complete working example.